# Keycloak realm client users authenticating in another keycloak realm containg client apps

Tags: realm, keycloak, openid-connect, idp

Hi Keycloak devs and gurus,

I wanted to setup keycloak, using openid-connect with 2 realms.

- Where realm1 will contain client(s) application
- And realm2 contains the users

  The users will then access the client applications in realm1 by authenticating through realm2. 
  I found this link --> [idp initiated sso using keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785427/idp-initiated-sso-using-keycloak), but it is implemented based on SAML not on openid-connect.

  Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Realms are independent entities (domains/databases/...), so I really don't understand how can you implement: `The users will then access the client applications in realm1 by authenticating through realm2`

Comment: @JanGaraj, here is an example --> https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki/Standalone-Keycloak-as-Identity-Provider

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can convert **realm2 as an idp keycloak OIDC** and connect realm2 to realm1 (by creating an idp in realm1). Then, configure the idp redirector in the browser authentication to automaticaly redirected to realm2.